# Ajuda com ArrayList

Tags: java, lista, ireport

Apenas os dois últimos elementos da minha Arraylist são enviados como datasource no ireport.
Tenho uma ArrayList que armazena dados lidos de tags em arquivos xml. Por exemplo, eu seleciono três arquivos xml com as mesmas tags porém com dados diferentes. Tenho um método que lê esses arquivos e vai preenchendo uma ArrayList, mas quando mando pro ireport só os dois últimos dados que são do ultimo xml são exibidos.

Código que permite a seleção dos arquivos e os manda para leitura, após a leitura uma lista é retornada e eu passo a lista como datasource:

```
  private void btnPegarArquivoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
    // Possibilita a seleção de vários arquivos
    chooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(true);

    // Apresenta a caixa de diálogo
    chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    // Retorna os arquivos selecionados. Este método retorna vazio se
    // o modo de múltipla seleção de arquivos não estiver ativada.
    File[] files = chooser.getSelectedFiles();

    for (File argumento : files) {
       System.err.println("Argumentos: " + argumento.getPath());
        caminho = argumento.getPath();
        LeitorXMLDOMMelhorado parser = new LeitorXMLDOMMelhorado();

        try {
            /* List<Cliente> */
            listaContatos = (ArrayList<Cliente>) parser.realizaLeituraXML(caminho);
            System.out.println("Valores: " + listaContatos);


            for(Cliente c : listaContatos){ 
                System.out.println("Nome no Arquivo xml: "+c.getNome());
                gerarRelatorio((ArrayList) listaContatos);
            } 
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.out.println("O parser não foi configurado corretamente.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.out.println("Problema ao fazer o parse do arquivo.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("O arquivo não pode ser lido.");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
```

Método que gera o relatório:

```
 public void gerarRelatorio(ArrayList list) {
    for (int i = 0; i < lista.size(); i++) {

        JasperReport report = null;

        try {
            InputStream inputStreamReal = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/br/com/testexml/relatorio/Teste.jrxml");
            report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(inputStreamReal);

        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TesteView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, null, new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(list));
            JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(print,
                    "C:\\relatorios/RelatorioClientes" + i + ".pdf");

        } catch (JRException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TesteView.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
}
```

Classe que faz a leitura do xml e preenche uma lista:

```
public class LeitorXMLDOMMelhorado {

public List<Cliente> realizaLeituraXML(String arquivoXML) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
    //fazer o parse do arquivo e criar o documento XML
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = db.parse(arquivoXML);

    //Passo 1: obter o elemento raiz
    Element raiz = doc.getDocumentElement();
    System.out.println("O elemento raiz é: " + raiz.getNodeName());

    //Passo 2: localizar os elementos filhos da agenda
    NodeList listaContatos = raiz.getElementsByTagName("contato");

    List<Cliente> lista = new ArrayList<Cliente>(listaContatos.getLength());

    //Passo 3: obter os elementos de cada elemento contato
    for (int i = 0; i < listaContatos.getLength(); i++) {

        //como cada elemento do NodeList é um nó, precisamos fazer o cast
        Element elementoContato = (Element) listaContatos.item(i);

        //cria um objeto Contato com as informações do elemento contato
        Cliente contato = criaContato(elementoContato);
        lista.add(contato);
        //System.err.println("Listaaaaaaa: " + lista);

        // System.err.println("Lista no metodo:"+lista);
    }

    return lista;
}

public String obterValorElemento(Element elemento, String nomeElemento) {
    //obtém a lista de elementos
    NodeList listaElemento = elemento.getElementsByTagName(nomeElemento);
    if (listaElemento == null) {
        return null;
    }
    //obtém o elemento
    Element noElemento = (Element) listaElemento.item(0);
    if (noElemento == null) {
        return null;
    }
    //obtém o nó com a informação
    Node no = noElemento.getFirstChild();
    return no.getNodeValue();
}

public Cliente criaContato(Element elemento) {
    Cliente contato = new Cliente();
    contato.setCod(Integer.parseInt(elemento.getAttributeNode("id").getNodeValue()));
    contato.setNome(obterValorElemento(elemento, "nome"));
    contato.setProduto(obterValorElemento(elemento, "produto"));
    contato.setCpf(obterValorElemento(elemento, "cpf"));
    contato.setValorCompra(Float.parseFloat(obterValorElemento(elemento, "valor")));

    return contato;
}
```

}

Como fica o relatório:
[image: Apenas os 2 valores do arquivo3.xml são listados]

E por fim é isso que é exibido na Saida:
[image: Resultado do System.out.println("Nome no Arquivo xml: "+c.getNome());]

Valeu galera.

Comment: se me permite, gostaria de adiciona um adendo sobre ArrayList: [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/195006/6789)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## O problema

Pela saída de log é possível ver que você está lendo 3 XMLs, cada um com dois clientes.

No programa, você chama a rotina de geração três vezes e dentro dessa rotina tem um laço `for` que gera um relatório para cada item da lista.

No final das contas, você está gerando o relatório 6 vezes. Duas vezes para os dois primeiros clientes, duas vezes com os dois do meio e duas vezes para os dois últimos.

O maior problema é que cada vez que o método geração é executado ele sobrescreve os que foram gerados anteriormente. Compreende?

## Solução: Relatório Único

Se o objetivo é gerar um único relatório com todos os clientes, você precisa ler os XMLs primeiro e adicionar os resultados em uma lista única.

Por exemplo, crie uma outra lista no método principal e adicione os itens das listas retornada da leitura de cada XML usando o método `addAll`.

Somente depois chame o método para gerar o relatório e faça a geração somente uma vez.

## Solução: Múltiplos Relatórios

Se o objetivo é gerar um relatório para cada XML, então o código está quase correto.

Entretanto, remova o `for` de dentro do método de geração do relatório. Adicione como parâmetro do método um contador que será usado no nome do arquivo. Finalmente, ao chamar esse método, passe um valor diferente para cada geração, de forma que o nome do arquivo gerado em cada execução seja diferente do anterior.

Comment: Muito Obrigado, com sua explicação as coisas ficaram mais claras.

Comment: Excelente! E seja bem-vindo ao [pt.so]!